# Running a powerscript as another user from Remote computer

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am trying to run a powershell script from a computer (name: Builds) on a remote computer (name: Test), both machine are running Windows 10. The script is as follows:

```
param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$buildPath)

$strScriptUser = "Test"
$strPass = "hld@1234"
$PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $strPass -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = new-object system.management.automation.PSCredential $strScriptUser,$PSS

Write $Credential.UserName

Start-Process powershell.exe "C:\Users\Test\Documents\PowerShellForContinua\Core.ps1 '$buildPath'" -Credential $Credential -Wait
```

When I run the above script on Test computer, locally it works fine. But when I try to execute this script from Builds computer it giving following error:

[image: Error executing script]

Although username and password are correct. Only things is that password contains special character. This is how I am calling the script

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to put your domain prefix before your username, or use the UPN (e.g. CONTOSO\Test or Test@contoso.com).

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the error? The username and/or password that you're passing to the Start-Process cmdlet is incorrect. Fix that.

Comment: The username and password are correct

Answer (score 0):

Cory Knutson's answer is right.  And MDMarra is correct.  The reason behind their answers will help you with authentication troubleshooting in the future.

**Your authentication is not correct.**

More specifically stated, you are not passing FULL credentials to the target host in a way that the target host can authenticate the user you are using.  There are three parts to authentication:

1. username
2. domain
3. password

Username and domain are typically joined together.  Generally, *username@domain* is used.  For Windows domains, *domain/username* was the standard starting with Windows NT until Windows Server 2003 Active Directory.  Windows still recognizes the old NT format, but for consistency, especially if you use non Windows Hosts in your enterprise, the *username@domain* format should be used.

You're telling the test host, "Run this script as the following user: test and the following password".  Given just a username, a stand alone Windows host assumes localhost as the domain.  Given just a username, a domain joined Windows host assumes localdomain.  You have to specify if you are using something different.